# jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String

Tags: java, hashmap, jackson, yaml

I have a yaml file that I want to read into Map:

```
events:
  key1: val1
  key2: val2
  key3: val3


public class EventGenerator {    
  private Map<String, String> events;

  public Map<String, String> getEvents() {
    return this.events;
  }

  public void setEvents() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.yaml");
            EventGenerator eventGenerator = mapper.readValue(fis, EventGenerator.class);
            fis.close();
            System.out.print(eventGenerator.getEvents());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

  }

}
```

This piece of code is working fine. But when I pass path of yaml file as a String parameter

```
public void setEvents(String filePath) {
// same code
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath)
// same code
}
```

I'm getting an exception

```
jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String
```

Can anyone explain this behavior and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: pls provide value of path variable.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/file.yaml"`And it's the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the issue. 
Setter method must follow strict POJO standards, i.e. `setEvents(Map events) {this.events = events};` and desearilization must go into another method.